# Override construct function in child class magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, construct

I want override a model class, for this I have made entry in di.xml and created a respective file on my custom module. My file is calling but now here apart from modify other functions I also need to modify `__construct()` function of base class. But I don't know how to do it -

Here is my base class construct function -

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $extensionFactory,
        $customAttributeFactory,
        $paymentData,
        $scopeConfig,
        $logger,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );

    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_session = $session;
    /*
     * set api key for payment  >> sandbox api key or live api key
     */
    if ($this->getDebugFlag()) {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->_helper->getConfigValue('api_key'));
    } else {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->_helper->getConfigValue('api_key'));
    }
}
```

I want to modify this construct function and want to add below more objects -

```
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

$this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
$this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
$this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
$this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
```

In my custom module's overrided class how can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your overrided class constructor should be as below:

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
array $data = []
 ) {
parent::__construct(
    $context,
    $registry,
    $extensionFactory,
    $customAttributeFactory,
    $paymentData,
    $scopeConfig,
    $logger,
    $session,
    $customerSession,
    $resource,
    $resourceCollection,
    $data
   );

$this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
$this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
$this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
$this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

NB: Don't forget to run setup:di:compile